# Finding number of combinations for similar items

Tags: combinations, inclusion-exclusion

I have 4 types of popsicle colors: Red, white, yellow, green.
In the grocery store, there's 11 popsicles of each type, all together 44 popsicles.
I need to find the number of combinations for choosing 26 of them.
No restrictions on the order of choosing, same types are consider the same.
I need to use either Inclusion–exclusion principle or Generating function.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "dots and lines" approach, the number of solutions in non-negative integers of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=26\tag{$*$}$$
is $C(29,3)$.  However, your problem is more complicated because we also have the condition that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\le11$.  We shall count the number of solutions by PIE (the principle of inclusion/exclusion).

Let $\cal U$ be the set of all solutions of $(*)$, and for $k=1,2,3,4$, let $A_k$ be the set of all solutions in which $x_k\ge12$.  Then the set of solutions that we wish to count is
$$\overline{A_1}\cap\overline{A_2}\cap\overline{A_3}\cap\overline{A_4}\ .$$
By PIE, the number we want is
$$\eqalign{|{\cal U}|{}-|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|
  &=|{\cal U}|-|A_1|-\cdots+|A_1\cap A_2|+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad{}-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-\cdots+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|\ .\cr}$$
To count $A_1$ we put $12$ dots aside, distribute the remainder over $4$ categories in $C(17,3)$ ways, then add the $12$ back to $x_1$ inorder to guarantee that $x_1\ge12$.  Similarly, to count $A_1\cap A_2$ we put aside $24$ dots, arrange the remaining $2$ in $C(5,2)$ ways, and add $12$ each back to $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Doing the rest similarly and noting that the later terms are zero gives the answer
$$C(29,3)-4C(17,3)+6C(5,3)\ .$$

**Comments**.

- "Dots and lines" is also known as "stars and bars", especially in the USA for some reason ;-)
- Instead of "putting dots aside" you can make a substitution $y_k=x_k-12$.  This works fine too, but IMHO the method I have given should help you to obtain an intuitive feel for the problem instead of just memorising techniques.